# Button doesn't refresh result when clicking

Tags: javascript

I have created a script which onclick loads the parent directory of a url. This parent directory should automatically refresh and give a new result every time, but it does not on live. While on local it does.

The link loads an entry in the DB randomly every time, see for example:
https://whereshouldieat.ie/restaurant/Burger/

```
<input type="button" class="btn-primary" value="Choose somewhere else!" onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href = '../<?php print $restaurant->food_type ?>/'; //one level up">
```

Every time this is clicked it creates a new result due to a class. It works fine on localhost but when using on live the result retains what it was originally, rather than refreshing to a new result of the /restaurant/burger

I am using cloudfare CDN I amn't sure if this would effect it.

How can I get this to work on live? Is there a better method to do this than:

```
onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href = '../<?php print $restaurant->food_type ?>/'; //one level up">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added in a piece of code to the end of the script

```
?nocache=' + (new Date()).getTime()
```

This will mean that website/server caching won't keep on bringing up the same link. But now at the end of the website there is a a string such as:

https://whereshouldieat.ie/restaurant/Burrito/?nocache=1498920656723